# Header information, headers already sent. I have tried looking at the code and eliminating whitespace as suggested but it didn't work

Tags: wordpress

This error i can't get rid off on my debug output in wordpress.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/zonafu54/public_html/www/wp-includes/functions.php:3382) in /home/zonafu54/public_html/www/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934
```

I posted something else in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572533/my-plugins-which-was-once-capable-of-writing-to-database-is-unable-to-do-it-anymo) but i forgot to enter some information so i'm reposting hoping i provide enough information.

I may have deleted some plugins forcefully. Specially that pesky WPSQT that wouldn't let me unistall it. And also their database tables i deleted manually.

If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's being caused by a plugin - have you tried going through all your plugins, switching each one off one at a time, and every time one is switched off refresh and see if the error has gone?

When it does disappear, you'll know it was (most likely) the one your just switched off.  A bit of trial and error should confirm this.